# Identifying foreign language in text

Tags: html, language, nlp

We are meant to implement some accessibility measures on a website, including one that requires that all words in a different language are properly identified, thanks to a `lang=xx` attribute.

Example:

```
<div>Hello John, how are you <span lang='fr'>aujourd'hui</span>?</div>
```

In our real life data, articles are in French and we need to tag non-French words.

We have about 2000 articles, for which we need to implement this, so we're trying to avoid a complete manual process.

I'm looking for some tool that would help me doing this. Basically, for each article, I'd extract the HTML content from our database, feed that content to the tool, and the tool would output the content with the additional `lang` attribute, or **at least indicate wich words are not in the original language**

**Edit**
I did find this but it only works with sentences: https://www.basistech.com/text-analytics/rosette/language-identifier/#try-the-demo